# undefined method from show.html.erb in rails cocoon nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a nested form via the cocoon gem, and all is working nicely; however, after filling out the nested form, I can't figure out how to display the nested form data after updating the form in the `show.html.erb`.

My code:

## developments_controller.rb

```
    class DevelopmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_development, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /developments or /developments.json
  def index
    @developments = Development.all
  end

  # GET /developments/1 or /developments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /developments/new
  def new
    @development = Development.new
  end

  # GET /developments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /developments or /developments.json
  def create
    @development = Development.new(development_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @development.save
        format.html { redirect_to @development, notice: "Development was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @development }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @development.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /developments/1 or /developments/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @development.update(development_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @development, notice: "Development was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @development }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @development.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /developments/1 or /developments/1.json
  def destroy
    @development.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to developments_url, notice: "Development was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_development
      @development = Development.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def development_params
      params.require(:development).permit(:name, :dev_type, :address, :description, :completion, :body_corp, listings_attributes: [:id, :status, :lot_number, :price, :listing_type, :bed, :bath, :car, :land_size, :house_size, :rent, :done, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

## development.rb (parent model)

```
class Development < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :listings, inverse_of: :development
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :listings, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: :true
end
```

## listing.rb (child model)

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :development
end
```

## _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @development do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :dev_type %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :dev_type %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :address %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :completion %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :completion %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body_corp %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :body_corp %>
  </div>
  <h3>Tasks</h3>
  <div id="listings">
    <%= f.fields_for :listings do |listing| %>
      <%= render 'listing_fields', f: listing %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add listing', f, :listings %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

## _listing_fields.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @listing do |f| %>
<h3>New Listing</h3>
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :status %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :status %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lot_number %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :lot_number %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :listing_type %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :listing_type %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :bed %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :bed %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :bath %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :bath %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :car %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :car %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :land_size %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :land_size %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :house_size %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :house_size %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :rent %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :rent %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove listing", f %>
</div>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

## show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @development.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Dev type:</strong>
  <%= @development.dev_type %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Address:</strong>
  <%= @development.address %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @development.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Completion:</strong>
  <%= @development.completion %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Body corp:</strong>
  <%= @development.body_corp %>
</p>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_development_path(@development) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', developments_path %>
```

I've tried calling on a few variations of the code on what's already in `show.html.erb`, such as `@development.listings`, `@listings` and `@development.listings_attributes`, but whenever I call on a `listings_attribute:` such as `:price`, `:status` etc. from the params in the `developments_controller.rb` I continually get an error undefined method error. I can't figure out where I'm going wrong, but I know the data is being stored, as it's present when I go to the `/edit` page on my localhost. I've been following the setup tutorial on https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon and from this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2iw5BAKBNA which have been great up until displaying the nested form data! The parent data displays no problems at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the error message with the stack trace to the question?

Comment: This line doesn’t look quite right: `has_many :listings, through :inverse_of: :development`

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan yep! So when I add something like `<p>
  <strong>status:</strong>
  <%= @development.listings.status %>
</p>` to the `show.html.erb` file, I get the error: undefined method `status' for #<Listing::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007fea455bacc0>

Comment: @hashrocket ahh yes, apologies, the `through` was part of some experimental code from another stack overflow post I was looking at. It should read like this: `has_many :listings, inverse_of: :development`. I'll edit and update the question to reflect that now.

Comment: You can’t call `@development.listings.status`. `@development.listings` is a collection. You have to iterate through it, then call `status` in each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call the `status` method on `@development.listings`, a collection. You should iterate over the collection and call the method on the `Listing` instance instead.

```
<% @development.listings.each do |listing| %>
  <%= listing.status %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Perfecto! Thank you so much, @hashrocket and Arun for posting!